# Kafka Streams GlobalKTable sychronization to applications

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

With working normal k-streams, kafka stores the offsets of each application on its internal offset topics. On a application restart, applications reprocess the topics depending on `auto.offset.reset` policy. This is indeed explained [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#fault-tolerance).

I am using kafka-stream's `GlobalKTable` to replicate the data over applications. However I'm a bit confused about applications' restarts since **it's not populated on applications whose id (`StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`) does not change** after restart (due to a deployment or a crash). Whenever I start a new instance of streams application with new id, `GlobalKTable` is populated.

A `GlobalKTable` is nothing different but a topic with log-compaction feature enabled. javadoc of creating a [`StreamsBuilder#globalTable`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#globalTable-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized-) states:

```
streamsBuilder.globalTable("some-topic", Materialized.as("kglobaltable-store"))
```

> Note that `GlobalKTable` always applies "auto.offset.reset" strategy
>   "earliest" regardless of the specified value in `StreamsConfig`.

Hence I expect, **regardless of the application id**, my streams applications read the `kglobaltable-store` topic from the start and populate store locally like this [github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/issues/140). It seems the topic the javadoc refers is `some-topic` instead of `kglobaltable-store`.

Is this the intended behaviour for `GlobalKTable`? And additionally is there a retention policy on topics which are backing `GlobalKTables`?

This behaviour also results in stale data on `kglobaltable-store` topic when we have a retention policy on `some-topic`. An example would be as follows:

At time t0, let;

some-topic: (1, a) -> (2, b) -> (1, c)

kglobaltable-store: [(1, c), (2, b)]

After some time (2, b) is subject to retention, I start my streams application (with a new id) and my `GlobalKTable` only stores the record (1, c) If this is the case.

**EDIT:** I am using `InMemoryKeyValueStore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `InMemoryKeyValueStore` I assume that you are hitting this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6711

As a workaround, you can delete the local checkpoint file (cf [GlobalKTable checkpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469293/globalktable-checkpoints)) for the global store -- this will trigger the bootstrapping on restart. Or you switch back to default `RocksDB` store.

Btw: For if you read a topic directly as a table or global-table, Kafka Streams will not create an additional changelog topic for fault-tolerance, but use the original input topic for this purpose (this reduces storage requirements within the Kafka cluster). Thus, those input topics should have log compaction enabled.